# MVC Routing issue 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, routes, http-status-code-404

Odd routing issue here. Every time i try to use the `ViewForm` link i am presented with a `Resources Not Found 404` error. When i use the `INDEX` or `CREATE` links i am routed to the correct functions in my Controller.

I have tried multiple different configurations of my links including these:

- `@Html.RouteLink("formView", New With { .formId = form.formId })`
  `@Html.Action("View", New With {.formId = form.formId})`

**RouteConfig.vb**

```
routes.MapRoute("form_list", "forms/list", New With {.controller = "Forms", .action = "Index"})
routes.MapRoute("form_view", "forms/view/{formId}", New With {.controller = "Forms", .action = "ViewForm"})
routes.MapRoute("form_create", "forms/{*formId}", New With {.controller = "Forms", .action = "Create"})
```

**FormsController.vb**

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
End Function

<ActionName("View")>
Function ViewForm(formId As Guid) As ActionResult
End Function

<HttpGet>
<ActionName("Create")>
Function Create_Get() As ActionResult
End Function

<HttpPost>
<ActionName("Create")>
Function Create_Post() As ActionResult
End Function
```

**View**

```
INDEX>>> <a ID="lnkSideBarForms" href="@Url.RouteUrl("form_list")">Forms</a>
ViewForm>>> <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("form_view", New With {.action = "ViewForm", .formId = form.formId})" title="@form.formName">@form.formName</a>
CREATE>>> <a class="btn-list-action btn btn-small pull-right" href="@Url.RouteUrl("form_create")"><i class="icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Form</a>
```

Comment: I am actually not very familiar with VB, but the problem could be that you are not passing a valid Guid. Try changing formId into a string and see if the issue is fixed. Another way could be marking formId as an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment on the OP was the issue.

My Controller Functions were looking for a `GUID`, but i was passing them a `string`.

Changing my Controller functions to the ones below resolved my problem.

**FormsController.vb**

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
End Function

<ActionName("View")>
Function ViewForm(formId As String) As ActionResult
End Function

<HttpGet>
<ActionName("Create")>
Function Create_Get() As ActionResult
End Function

<HttpPost>
<ActionName("Create")>
Function Create_Post() As ActionResult
End Function
```